# CodeIgniter validation logic

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm building a small application that will basically display 3 forms... the first one is optional, the second not and the third not. I'd like each form to be a separate url(controller). While reading the documentation for the CodeIgniter form_validation, it appears that the form can only submit to it's self to validate. If that's the case, the forms would keep showing on the same page... he's basically what I have... and commented in what i'd like to do...

```
class Index extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

        function index()
        {
        //load front page that contains first form...
                $content['title'] = 'Home';
                $content['view'] = 'pages/index';
                $this->load->view('template/default',$content);

        }
        function step_two()
        {
           //recieve information from front page. validate form. If validation is 
           //successful continue to step_two(url) if it fails redirect 
           //to front page with error...

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('serial', 'Serial Number', 'required');

          if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
          {
           //return to front page...
          }else{
           //do necessary work and load step_two view   
          } 


        }

}

?>
```

This is a snippet from my idea. But what I'm noticing is that you can't have form validation unless the form submits to it's self. Any ideas? Should I validate the form then just redirect to the new url/function?

Thanks guys...

Comment: Redirect on successful validation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is how you do it

Controller -

```
public function step1()
{
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform1');
        }
        else
        {
            //do something to post data
            redirect('/controller/step2');
        }
}


public function step2()
{
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform2');
        }
        else
        {
            //do something to post data

            redirect('/controller/step3');
        }
}
```

so answer to your question is yes, you keep these in the same method and redirect on successful validation.

Comment: So if say... I wanted to prevent people from accessing step3 unless the sucessfully validated form 2, would you just set a session variable after successful validation and check for it in the step3 function?

Comment: Yes, Session variable is not a bad idea. Or it depends how these forms are interlinked - for example - if step1 creates new db record then perhaps you can do a quick check before you show form in step2